# Should I rollback an edit that I reviewed and rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I'm speaking of [this suggested edit.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11094047)

I had rejected the edit, on reason that it should've been an answer as it's own, and I hope it's somewhat obvious as to why. The answer was changed from offering one suggestion to three, and added a little preamble that completely changed the voice of the post.

I'm a little reluctant to rollback the edit, especially because I had already rejected it in review. To rollback would... be undemocratic.

Look at the post, the author of the suggested edit also left this note (at the time the edit was approved):

> Since most of the mods can't even **read** the OP's question `(installing third-party software is not an option`...) here is an bash alias/function to map wget to curl: `function _wget() { curl "${1}" -o $(basename "${1}") ; }; alias wget='_wget'`

I left this comment:

> @Michaelangelo No one here are mods, we're just community members that are trying to help. If you're trying to answer the question, you should feel free to make an answer of your own.

I didn't really want to reference the edit or the review, but thought it was strange to see the comment at around the time the edit was approved.

What should I do in these sorts of situations?

Comment: Yes.  You have unrestricted edit privileges for a reason.  I did it for you in this case.  Hopefully the editor follows up on your comment with their own answer; if not, you (or anyone) can add it as their own.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Thank you, but it doesn't feel right. I've had a say in reviewing that edit, of which three other people disagreed. Yeah, those three other people were probably robo-reviewers (look at their edit stats - just don't look at mine, I'm the opposite) but is it still correct to essentially go against the result of review?

Comment: Well, you could have chosen "Reject and Edit" to unilaterally reject the edit (regardless of the quality of your further edit, or if you immediately revert it during the grace period).  And you can freely edit the post at any time without review.  So if you've thought about it -- and you clearly have -- and decided that the other reviewers erred, I don't see any reason why you wouldn't fix their mistake.  (If the edit is re-suggested, then you can try to engage the editor with comments or bring it to meta rather than edit-warring.)

Comment: As a side note, edit stats are not a reliable measure of robo-reviewing. Lots of users will skip any edit they think is questionable, which will skew the stats. Also, the majority of robo-reviewers will auto-reject instead of approve because there are no known good review audits, meaning that if you always hit reject, you will never fail an audit. The majority of those users who are approving bad edits actually think that they are helping, and just don't know the current policies around editing.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom It would be more productive to teach Zizouz to stop bike shedding issues.

Comment: @Michaelangelo while I also disagree with your edit (and can't really understand your comment), [the answerer does not](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17094214/7).

Comment: @AndrasDeak How actually _reading_ what the OP asked and focusing on the _solution_ instead of bike shedding: `How can I do an HTTP GET from a Un*x shell script on a stock OS X system? (installing third-party software is not an option,`.  There are multiple solutions to the OP's problem: 1) Use curl, 2) Write a wrapper for wget to call curl, 3) install wget a) from Brew, or b) manually.  What do you not understand about the OP's question??

Comment: @Michaelangelo thanks for clarifying your point. I didn't *read* OP's question. My point is that you seemed to be updating an answer that is 2.5 years old with completely new information. I disagree with such (suggested) edits, since I think they should either be new answers, or comments left for the answerer (out of courtesy, in my opinion). Many disagree with me here, but I would've also rejected your suggestion. Anyway, the main factual information in my previous comment was that your edit has been incorporated into the answer after all.

Comment: The power trip is strong here.

It would be one thing if the editor were taking something away, which I could understand as vandalism, but the edit instead improved on an answer that not only allows for backwards compat, but also works currently.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How invested are you in the outcome?

If you truly believe it is a bad edit, and you are willing to put forth the effort to babysit the post until the edit is approved or rejected, it is definitely acceptable to rollback an edit that you feel should not have been applied in the first place.

If you are truly invested in the post, and are willing to further babysit the post for any future edits, or engage the editor in the comments or chat, that is also acceptable. However, I would not suggest engaging in an edit war.

Keep in mind that two rollbacks close together in the revision history will raise an auto flag. After that, if you want to provide more information in a custom flag to help the moderator make an informed decision, that is usually appreciated.

So, in summary, invest as much effort as you want to invest, but if an edit war ensues, don't take it further than is necessary, let a moderator make the final decision.